# Using custom fonts hosted on AWS S3 in a Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, fonts, amazon-s3

I have fonts from typography.com that I moved to production and uploaded to my AWS S3 Bucket to use on my Wordpress site. I have done everything that typography.com has told me to do, but the fonts still are not being displayed. Has anyone gone through this before and can point me in the right direction? I added an @import statement in style.css in my theme to the url that typography.com gave me. I also have a wp_enqueue function in functions.php that I have uploaded to the S3 server.

```
 add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_fonts' );
function my_fonts(){ ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cloud.typography.com/7783912/761788/css/fonts.css">
<?php
}
```

The fonts are still not being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's the content of `fonts_used.css`, according to your browser? (and is that running into network problems according to your browser's devtools?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it is the link that typography.com gave me.

Comment: I updated the code in my question.

Comment: that still leaves the question "what is the browser *actually* doing". Your PHP looks fine, but PHP runs on the server, so let's move to looking ath what the browser does: do you see the `<link>` show up in the HTML source when you load your page in the browser? If you do, does the browser report any errors in the console and/or network tab when you inspect the page with the dev tools? If I try to open your link href, I get a 403 forbidden, so I assume it's domain-restricted: are you loading it from the correct domain?

Comment: It doesn't look like the link is there in the html file. I've read that AWS takes time to update the files so that maybe the problem

Comment: AWS takes *a few seconds* to update, unless you're running multiple nodes with load balancing and complex routing =) It sounds more like perhaps the `add_action` is happening before you've defined that `my_fonts` function so: turn on error reporting for PHP and see what it says?

Comment: well the add_action line is before the my_fonts function is declared so does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to include stylesheets is to use [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style). Using this function will also allow you to declare this font as a dependency for other stylesheets. You should also use the `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` hook, as opposed to `'wp_head'`:

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'typography', '//cloud.typography.com/7783912/761788/css/fonts.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

If you're still having issues at this point, make sure you have the proper permissions to GET this file from the Typography cloud server.